# Is it possible to use this code in a windows service?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating an internal inactivity logger for work, we initially wanted this to be a windows form application with a hidden windows form that works in the background, however the program appears in the task manager and we now want this code to be used in a windows service, I was wondering if this is possible? if so I'd like some help implementing that =]

this is the code for the Application

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AccessEye;
using System.Linq;
using EasyNetQ;
using EasyNetQ.Topology;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using NLog;
using ProtoBuf;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection; 

namespace LogProgram
{

    public partial class AppForm : Form
    {

        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private Screensaver watcher;
        public Inactivity inactivity;
        IAdvancedBus bus;
        IExchange exchange;

        public AppForm()
        {

                InitializeComponent();
                ConfigureForm();

                // todo: should be in setting
                int pollingInterval = 5000;

                inactivity = new Inactivity(pollingInterval);
                inactivity.Inactive += inactivity_Inactive;
                inactivity.Active += inactivity_Active;
                inactivity.InactivityThresholdMs = 5 * 1000; // todo: should be in setting
                inactivity.Start();
                watcher = new Screensaver(pollingInterval);
                watcher.ScreensaverOff += watcher_ScreensaverOff;
                watcher.ScreensaverOn += watcher_ScreensaverOn;
                watcher.Start();
                SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
                SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
                LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
                // todo: connection string should be in setting
                bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;
                exchange = Exchange.DeclareTopic("UserActivity", true, false, null);
                var fanout = Exchange.DeclareFanout("FanoutExchange", true, false, null);
                fanout.BindTo(exchange, new[] { "#" });


        }




        public void ConfigureForm()
        {
            this.Hide();
            TrayDisplayer.Visible = false;
        }

        public void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
        {
            using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
            {
                DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

                int t = (int)data.EventType;

                EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

                if (eventType == null)
                {
                    eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                    {
                        Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                        Id = (int)data.EventType
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
                db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static string GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(Enum value)
        {
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        private void AppForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }


        void watcher_ScreensaverOn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOn;
            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        void watcher_ScreensaverOff(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.ScreensaverOff;
            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();

            switch (e.Reason)
            {
                case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                    data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Lock;
                    break;
                case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                    data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Unlock;
                    break;
            }

            PublishLogData(data);
        }

        public void PublishLogData(AccessEye.LogData LogData)
        {
            WriteLogDataToDb(LogData);

            if (!bus.IsConnected) return;

            try
            {
                using (var publishChannel = bus.OpenPublishChannel())
                {
                    publishChannel.Publish(exchange, LogData.EventType.ToString(), new Message<LogData>(LogData));
                }
            }
            catch (EasyNetQException)
            {
                //todo: handle
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T instance)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private static T DeSerialize<T>(byte[] data)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                return Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            bus.Dispose();
        }

        public void inactivity_Active(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            inactivity.Stop();
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Active;
            PublishLogData(data);
            inactivity.Start();

        }

        public void inactivity_Inactive(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inactivity.Stop();
            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Inactive;
            PublishLogData(data);
            inactivity.Start();
        }

        public void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var data = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
            data.EventType = UserStateEvents.Logoff;
            PublishLogData(data);
            Logger.Trace("Logged off");
            }



        }


    }
```

UPDATE

Error   1   } expected  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    36  10  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   2   Method must have a return type  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    44  16  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   3   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    230 28  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   4   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    233 5   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    10  14  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'AccessEye' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    12  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'EasyNetQ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    14  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   8   The type or namespace name 'EasyNetQ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    15  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   9   The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    17  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   10  The type or namespace name 'NLog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    18  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   11  The type or namespace name 'ProtoBuf' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    19  7   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   12  'UserActivityMonitorBackGround.Service1.Logger' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    38  36  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   13  The name 'LogManager' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    38  52  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   14  The type or namespace name 'Screensaver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    39  17  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   15  The type or namespace name 'Inactivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    40  16  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   16  The type or namespace name 'IAdvancedBus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    41  9   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   17  The type or namespace name 'IExchange' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    42  9   UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   18  The type or namespace name 'Inactivity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    53  34  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   19  The type or namespace name 'Screensaver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    58  31  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   20  The name 'LogManager' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    64  17  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   21  The name 'RabbitHutch' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    66  23  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   22  The name 'Exchange' does not exist in the current context   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    67  28  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   23  The name 'Exchange' does not exist in the current context   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    68  30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   24  'UserActivityMonitorBackGround.Service1' does not contain a definition for 'Hide' and no extension method 'Hide' accepting a first argument of type 'UserActivityMonitorBackGround.Service1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    79  18  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   25  The name 'TrayDisplayer' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    80  13  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   26  The type or namespace name 'LogData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    83  38  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   27  The type or namespace name 'LogService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    85  33  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   28  The type or namespace name 'DbLogData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    87  17  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   29  The name 'AutoMapper' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    87  37  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   30  The type or namespace name 'LogData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    87  59  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   31  The type or namespace name 'DbLogData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    87  68  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   32  The type or namespace name 'EventType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    91  17  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   33  The type or namespace name 'EventType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    95  55  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   34  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    125 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   35  The name 'AccessEye' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    126 30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   36  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    132 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   37  The name 'AccessEye' does not exist in the current context  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    133 30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   38  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    139 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   39  The name 'UserStateEvents' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    144 38  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   40  The name 'UserStateEvents' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    147 38  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   41  The type or namespace name 'AccessEye' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    154 36  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   42  The type or namespace name 'LogData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    164 96  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   43  The type or namespace name 'Message' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    164 88  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   44  The type or namespace name 'EasyNetQException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    167 20  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   45  The name 'Serializer' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    177 17  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   46  The name 'Serializer' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    186 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   47  The type or namespace name 'FormClosingEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    190 55  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   48  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    199 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   49  The name 'UserStateEvents' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    200 30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   50  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    209 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   51  The name 'UserStateEvents' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    210 30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   52  The name 'LogDataFactory' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    218 24  UserActivityMonitorBackGround
Error   53  The name 'UserStateEvents' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\reece.cottam\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\OsWatch\UserActivityMonitorBackGround\Service1.cs    219 30  UserActivityMonitorBackGround

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a "can you solve this for me"-site. You should try and do this yourself first, and then come back here if you need help with something specific. Right now, it is unclear if you have a question or just want help implementing your program.

Comment: What does the `ScreenSaver` class look like?

Comment: First, try to move the code to a class that has no reference to System.Windows.Forms. If you succeed, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

**No**,this wont work..

A service doesn't have a UI component.So,you cant show a `form` in service..It's not used for showing User Interface..

---

If you want to hide your winform from taskbar,you can just do this

```
yourForm.ShowInTaskBar=false;
```

You can also hide your winform from taskmanager but am not aware of how to implement it.you can google for it..

Comment: This needs to be re-written specifically with a windows service in mind

Comment: @ReeceCottam use service if you want to continuously work in the background..then if you want to show `form`(application) you can invoke your application from service using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309426/call-windows-application-in-windows-service) method

Comment: @ReeceCottam indeed..